# Mac OS Apache: как настроить виртуальный хост на 3000 порт?

Tags: reactjs, apache, macos, apache2

Я делаю приложение на React. Запускаю его через команду `npm run dev` и оно открывается по адресу `http://localhost:3000`.

Так же у меня работает на локалке бекенд, который настроен так, что работает на домене
`http://api.home.me`. Настройку делаю через виртуальные хосты.

Сейчас есть ошибка с CORS, поэтому постоянно должен открывать хром с отключенным CORS. Думал настроить apache, что бы он смотрел на 3000 порт и открывал реакт приложение. Пример конфига:

```
<VirtualHost *:3000>
        DocumentRoot "/Users/taruk/Sites/home/frontend/web"
        ServerName discode.me
        ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/home.me-error_log"
        CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/home.me-access_log" common

        <Directory "/Users/taruk/Sites/home/frontend/web">
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Но так не работает. Может что может подсказать, как сделать?

Comment: Запускать бек-энд на localhost ?

Comment: он и запущен на локалке, просто настроил через домен

Comment: домен смотрит локально

Comment: пропишите в бэке `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` заголовок

Comment: прописано, не помогает. если делать get запрос - все ок, но если post или put - сразу ошибка